# Como funciona a tag <class> no arquivo persistence.xml no jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa noite.
Eu estou iniciando nos estudos do jpa, e em um momento me deparei com a seguinte situação, eu preenchi o arquivo persistence.xml da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="exercicios-jpa">
                <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
                <class>modelo.basico.Usuario</class>
                <class>modelo.basico.Estado</class>
                <class>modelo.basico.Cidade</class>
                <properties>
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/curso_java"/>
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="12345678"/>

                        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Ele funcionou perfeitamente, mas em outra ocasião eu preenchi o mesmo arquivo só que esqueci de adicionar a tag class , e mesmo assim funcionou normalmente, acredito que isso ocorra porque só a annotation @Entity já é o suficiente para informar a classe, diante disso fiquei com dúvida de qual o real uso da tag, já que pelo visto ela não é obrigatória.
Eu pesquisei, mas só encontrei respostas subjetivas, e acho que sirva para casos em que hajam mais de uma unidade de persistência no arquivo, para identificar a qual unidade cada classe pertença, porém eu gostaria da resposta certa para que eu não crie um conceito errado. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: A resposta em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780341/2241463

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu já vi esse publicação, mas ela não sanou completamente minhas dúvidas, por exemplo, não informar a tag e as classes pode me gerar algum problema?